# Error in read.fwf when header=TRUE

Tags: r, import, fixed-width

I have simulated data that looks like this:

```
LastName   Date      email                                                    CreditCardNum   AgeZip  Amount
Paul       21/02/14  Aliquam.fringilla@dolordapibus.co.uk                     4241033422900360 6738851$14.39
Bullock      2/7/2014adipiscing.fringilla@lectusjusto.org                     5178789953524240 3336538$498.31
Mcmahon     11/5/2013lobortis.ultrices@lacus.org                              5389589582467450 7734302$92.44
Walters    25/09/13  consectetuer.cursus.et@sitamet.org                       5157094536097720 7794007$206.60
Franco     17/06/13  et@disparturientmontes.ca                                 345477952996264 2415873$89.12
```

and this is how I'm attempting to import it into R, with headers:

```
w <- c(11,10,57,16,3,5,8)
df <- read.fwf("data.txt",widths=w,stringsAsFactors=F)
names(df) <- df[1,]; df <- df[-1,]
```

The reason I'm not using `header=T` is that it gives me the error:

```
Error in read.table(file = FILE, header = header, sep = sep, row.names = row.names,  :  more columns than column names
```

which just isn't true. I know the widths (`w`) are correct. So where is this error coming from? My solution works fine, I'd just like to understand what's happening.

Comment: Can you please provide your `w` vector so that this is (more) reproducible?

Comment: Yes, sorry: `w <- c(11,10,57,16,3,5,8)`. Edited.

Comment: I'm a little unclear now what your question is. Did you want to know why the error was being thrown? or were you after an elegant workaround? Your proposed method of specifying `header=F` seems fine.

Comment: I'm wondering why the error is arising in the first place. Edited again.

Comment: Well, it's because you need to ensure your header row conforms to the specification of `sep`, which by default is `\t`. Yours does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify `header=TRUE`, then, as per `?read.fwf`, you must ensure that the column names are separated by `sep`. The default is for names to be separated by `\t` (the tab character) and this must not be true for your data.

The following works just fine:

```
w <- c(11, 10, 57, 16, 3, 5, 8)

read.fwf(widths=w, header=TRUE, sep='|', 
file=textConnection('LastName   |Date      |email                                                    |CreditCardNum   |Age|Zip  |Amount
Paul       21/02/14  Aliquam.fringilla@dolordapibus.co.uk                     4241033422900360 6738851$14.39
Bullock      2/7/2014adipiscing.fringilla@lectusjusto.org                     5178789953524240 3336538$498.31
Mcmahon     11/5/2013lobortis.ultrices@lacus.org                              5389589582467450 7734302$92.44
Walters    25/09/13  consectetuer.cursus.et@sitamet.org                       5157094536097720 7794007$206.60
Franco     17/06/13  et@disparturientmontes.ca                                 345477952996264 2415873$89.12'))
```

Comment: I was wondering what the "sep" argument was supposed to be used for in `read.fwf()`. Kinda defeats the purpose imo. Either way, I was hoping for a solution that didn't require me to modify the actual data, even if the modification is small and can be easily automated. Also note that `w` is different from what you (justifiably) assumed it would be; see my comment above.

Comment: Just noticed that I combined age and zip. I'll edit my post. I was also under the impression that the headers of `fwf` data were typically the same width as the subsequent rows, so I agree with you about the redundancy.

Comment: They are the same width, it's just that the spacing is off. There's leading and trailing whitespace that I trim after this step.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Ah, sorry - I wasn't commenting on your data.. what I meant was that, since the columns of `fwf` headers are typically the same width as the columns of subsequent rows, the `sep` argument is generally redundant.

Comment: Just hit this issue - thought I was losing my mind until I came across this question. I can't imagine this was what was intended!

Comment: @thelatemail - yes, it seems pretty odd