# read.fwf() with column names and two kind of sep in R

Tags: r

I have similar issue with [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592616/error-in-read-fwf-when-header-true)

My data is like (no first line in my txt file)

```
----*----1----*----2----*---
Region                 Value
New York, NY        66,834.6
Kings, NY           34,722.9
Bronx, NY           31,729.8
Queens, NY          20,453.0
San Francisco, CA   16,526.2
Hudson, NJ          12,956.9
Suffolk, MA         11,691.6
Philadelphia, PA    11,241.1
Washington, DC       9,378.0
Alexandria IC, VA    8,552.2
```

my attempt is

```
#fwf data2
path <- "fwfdata2.txt"
data6 <- read.fwf(path, 
            widths=c(17, -3, 8), 
            header=TRUE,
            #sep=""
            as.is=FALSE)
data6
```

with answer

```
> data6
                  Region.................Value
New York, NY                          66,834.6
Kings, NY                             34,722.9
Bronx, NY                             31,729.8
Queens, NY                            20,453.0
San Francisco, CA                     16,526.2
Hudson, NJ                            12,956.9
Suffolk, MA                           11,691.6
Philadelphia, PA                      11,241.1
Washington, DC                         9,378.0
Alexandria IC, VA                      8,552.2
> dim(data6)
[1] 10  1
```

So problem is that as my data separated by "," and "". It will generate error as follow when i add sep="".

```
Error in read.table(file = FILE, header = header, sep = sep, row.names = row.names,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `read.fwf` expects the header to be sep-separated, and the data to be fixed width:

```
header: a logical value indicating whether the file contains the
        names of the variables as its first line.  If present, the
        names must be delimited by ‘sep’.

   sep: character; the separator used internally; should be a
        character that does not occur in the file (except in the
        header).
```

I'd skip the header to read the data, then read the header by reading the first line only:

```
> data = read.fwf(path,widths=c(17,-3,8),head=FALSE,skip=1,as.is=TRUE)
> heads = read.fwf(path,widths=c(17,-3,8),head=FALSE,n=1,as.is=TRUE)
> names(data)=heads[1,]
> data
   Region               Value
1  New York, NY      66,834.6
2  Kings, NY         34,722.9
3  Bronx, NY         31,729.8
4  Queens, NY        20,453.0
5  San Francisco, CA 16,526.2
6  Hudson, NJ        12,956.9
7  Suffolk, MA       11,691.6
8  Philadelphia, PA  11,241.1
9  Washington, DC     9,378.0
10 Alexandria IC, VA  8,552.2
```

If you want the `Region` as a factor then use `as.is=FALSE` (as in your example) when reading the data, but you must use `as.is=TRUE` when reading the header otherwise it gets converted to numbers.

Did you also want to split the region into comma-separated parts and turn the comma-separated numbers into numeric values? You didn't say.

Comment: Thanks for yr reply. So...i must read the data separately if header and core data have different sep.

Comment: as I read it, `sep` is **only** ever used to read a header. For a fixed width file there is no `sep` in the core data, the data is defined by its width, not by a separator.